# When should the audio .play method start playing the audio?

Tags: javascript, audio

When I run the following...

```
<audio preload="auto" id="gameFill">
<source src="sounds/gameAttack.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

...

```
function sleep(ms) {
  date = Date.now();
  currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < ms);
}
```

...

```
document.getElementById("gameFill").play(); 
console.log("A");
sleep(5000);
console.log("B");
```

...the following happens...

1. "A" appears in the console.
2. A 5 second wait occurs.
3. "B" appears in the console.
4. The sound plays.

Why doesn't the sound start playing before the 5 second wait?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Probably because the thread that is used to start the playing, is the same thread that is occupied by your while-loop. You should _never_ use this sleep method outside of testing purposes for many reasons, including this one.

Comment: Webpages are single-threaded (unless you use Web Workers, but you don't), so synchronous code execution freezes the page. If a synchronous function takes too long to execute, this effect becomes observable. You should replace your `sleep` function with an asynchronous one.

Comment: I would have thought that in a single thread, each statement would be executed one at a time, in order. Something seems to be holding back the playing of the audio and allowing subsequent statements to execute first.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how browsers do this internally, but something very similar happens when updating the DOM. The changes you make to the UI will be queued and only be applied once the execution has finished. Either way it should be a non-issue, since completely blocking the thread should not be done in the first place.